# Python multiprocessing list manipulation

Tags: python-3.x

This is just an example, I know I could just print the list out.

```
   testlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    
    def exam():
        print(testlist[0])
        del testlist[0]
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        for _ in range(10):
            exam();
```

^^^ This prints my desired result of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

```
testlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    def exam():
        print(testlist[0])
        del testlist[0]
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        for _ in range(10):
            Process(target=exam).start()
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

^^^ This just prints out 1, 1, 1, 1, 1... etc. I want the above result but with multiprocessing.